# How to check for erros on Ubuntu Hardy?

Tags: ubuntu-8.04

I have just installed memcache and eAccelerator on an Ubuntu Hardy box and prior to hosting an application on it wanted to check for any type of errors either thrown by PHP or by other modules. How do I do this?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tail /var/log/apache2/error.log` unless you've changed the log directives in your virtual host/Apache configuration.